# Getting VB.net Webforms Project to work in Jetbrains Rider

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, compatibility, rider

I started a new job and we're currently using Visual Studio as an IDE. It's not a requirement, so I decided that I would like to use Jetbrains Rider for my work. I use Rider with C# for my development within Unity3D so I am already really familiar with it.

I've been having a few issues trying to get Rider to work with our existing projects.

1. If I try to open the Visual Studio solution **in Rider**, I receive a bunch of build errors that don't exist when running in VS. They are related to the .NET version defaulting to 4.0.xx. The project is targeted to 4.5.2 in Visual Studio. I cannot access the project settings in Rider to change the .NET version to 4.5.2. I receive an error *`"Unable to edit properties of this type of project"`*.
2. If I try to create a new solution via Rider, I cannot import the working files as a project. I must create a new project; only getting the option to create an ASP.NET **MVC** style project, and not the **Web Forms** type that I need.
3. Creating a solution and using the ASP.NET **MVC** style project then adding the folders *"works"* as in it will build the project. But it won't index the folders correctly and I have to modify a lot of my references to a namespace. (This wouldn't be a problem if I was the only developer on this project, but I am not.)
4. I've installed older versions of Rider to see if this could work (2017.3.1) and the same issues still occur.

If it comes down to it, I will just develop using Visual Studio, but I'm hoping someone understands what I am going through and perhaps has a solution.

Comment: Just advice and complete opinion and I'm assuming you're part of a team.  If your workplace is using Visual Studio, you would be plain better off to stick with it.  Avoid the compatibility issues all together.  Remember that if/when you get this running in your IDE you teammates may very well have the same issues going back the other way.  Fully understand you want to stick with familiar and 100% know VS has its issues but why make things hard on yourself.

Comment: Rider was meant to be a C# IDE, so how much VB.NET support there is questionable (F# might be more feasible). Even Microsoft stopped adding new things into VB and you need to reconsider your plan forward.

Comment: And worse is support for webforms since it can sort of edit such projects but can't create new web form pages.  And attempting to create a MVC project and running webforms is even more silly. MVC projects are 100% different system and architecture. MVC projects have ZERO to do with webforms.

Comment: @Hursey, yeah.. I just ended up staying with Visual Studio. The team has plans to get out of VB webforms some day, so i'll just wait for that opportunity to revaluate if I can make the switch.